# Inter process communication from python to cpp program

Tags: python, c++, ipc

Suppose there are 3 files: f1.cpp, f2.py, f3.cpp.
I am running the command on linux terminal as follows:

```
$./f1.out | python3 f2.py | ./f3.out
```

The output of f1 goes perfectly into the input of f2. Also, f2's output goes perfectly into f3. I am displaying the output in f3. f1 generates input for f2 after a particular interval. In this interval, I need to enter a user input in f3 file so that it can give an output accordingly during that pause.
I tried debugging my code and I found that although my final output without user input is generated by f3, my user input is not being read. Somebody help!!

Comment: f3 is reading the output of f2, now it can't read the input from the console. You may open yet another input for reading tty device and read user inputs. Look at the example https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138342/how-to-read-write-to-tty-device.

Comment: user input is being read by `f1`, you'd need to pass it on somehow

Comment: @AlanBirtles according to me, it is being read by f2. I tried printing my input in f2 but it isn't printing. When I press ctrl+C to exit, it gives a keyboard interrupt in f2 file. I am stuck at this :(

Comment: There is no way f1 can except input as there isn't any cin line in it

Comment: It doesn't matter where you are trying to read the input, the console feeds in to `f1`, the output of `f1` is the input for `f2`, the output of `f2` is the input to `f3` and the output of `f3` goes to the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have already declared from your command that f3 should take input from f2's output and f2 should take input from f1's output, there is no straightforward way to give console input to f3 now.

The best way here would be (assuming you are only the author of f1 and f2 also) you can just read that user input in f1 only and immediately print it

```
cin >> input;
cout << input;
```

so that it will be passed to f2's input. You can do a similar thing in f2 also

```
inp = str(input)
print(inp)
```

hence passing that to f3 as you wanted.

But if you don't want to do it this way or if you are not the author of f1 and f2, I would suggest you launch f3 in a separate terminal window and use a named pipe(FIFO) for communication between f2 and f3. Since the communication would be happening through a FIFO, the stdin would still be pointing to the keyboard and you can type input to f3.

**Edit**

Another way you can do it is(although, I'm not sure how healthy this is), you can spawn a new thread before sleeping. Take input in new thread and terminate that new thread once input is taken. The new thread will be running as long as input is not given. In the main thread sleep for 5 seconds and when main thread wakes up, forcefully terminate the new thread using something like `pthread_kill`.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks a lot. In f1 file, I am using sleep command for pausing the output for 5 secs. My project needs me to accept a user input during that period of time. How can I achieve this.
PS: My goal is to generate random inputs from f1 file for f2, working something in f2 and using the results of f2 in f3. During the pause in f1, I want to enter a user input which is actually needed in f3.
I would really appreciate if you could help me :)

Comment: What worked, exactly?

Comment: Do you need to pause in f1 or is it something you are doing to wait for input?

Comment: I read the input in f1 and output in subsequently into next files. What I need to do is to pause f1 for a given number of seconds. This will send the output for f1 into f2 and then into f3. During this pause, I want to input a string that is required in f3. But it would have to pass from f1. Now the problem faced is that if I use sleep command in f1, my program would still get stuck at getline.

Basically what I want is to add a timer to getline function so that it waits for 5 seconds for any input. If it doesn't get any input, it skips.

Comment: You are not open to running f3 in a different terminal window?

Comment: No, everything has to be done on same window

Comment: What I need to do is: construct a driver function that uses pipes() and fork() to do the above task i.e. generate random input from f1, pass f1 output to f2 and do some operation, pass f2 output to f3 and display final output. f1 will wait for 5 seconds before generating second input for f2. Meanwhile, my program should except a user input required in f3 for a new output.

Comment: I added another method to my answer which might suit your need. check it out.